# Find the longest match of 2 integers in R

Tags: r, match

I have 2 lists with numbers and I need to match the values of one list with the other. The match has to be done based on the beginning of the number. It has to return the row_id of the longest match that is possible.

```
lookup value: 12345678

find_list:
a   1
b   12
c   123
d   124
e   125
f   1234
g   1235
```

In this example we would have a match with `a,b,c,f` and R must return `f`. Since `f` is the longest and therefore the best match.

I now have used the `startsWith` function in R. From that answer I choose the value that is the longest. But the problem is that the lists are huge. I have 18.5 Million lookup values and 300,000 possible values in the `find_list` and R crashes after a while.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method in base R.

```
# construct a vector of all possible matches for the lookup value
lookupVec <- floor(lookup * (10 ^ (-1 * (0:(nchar(lookup)-1)))))
```

This returns

```
lookupVec
[1] 1234567  123456   12345    1234     123      12       1

# find the value of the first variable that matches the maximum value
# lower values in the vector

dat$V1[which.min(match(dat$V2, lookupVec))]
[1] f
Levels: a b c d e f g
```

You can probably speed this up by replacing base R's `match` function with the `fastmatch` function from the package of the same name as it will hash the table values if you search over these a second time.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 12L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 1234L, 1235L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -7L))

lookup <- 12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find_list$X[which.max(sapply(find_list$find_list, function(myX)
    attr(gregexpr(myX, lookup_value)[[1]], "match.length")))]
#[1] "f"
```

**DATA**

```
find_list = structure(list(X = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), find_list = c(1L, 
12L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 1234L, 1235L)), .Names = c("X", "find_list"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

lookup_value = 12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a smarter way of doing what you want but the following produces the result in the question.
You will need package `stringi` installed.
First, the data in the question.

```
lookup <- "12345678"
find_list <- read.table(text = "
a   1
b   12
c   123
d   124
e   125
f   1234
g   1235
")
find_list$V2 <- as.character(find_list$V2)
```

Now the code.

```
inx <- which(stringi::stri_detect(lookup, regex = find_list$V2))
inx <- inx[which.max(nchar(find_list$V2[inx]))]
find_list[inx, ]
#  V1   V2
#6  f 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option in case you can convert your find_list into a `data.table`:

```
y <- 123456789

x <- data.table(sample(1:1000000, 1000000, replace = T))  # find list
n <- round(log(y, base = 10)) + 1  # number of digits
z <- floor(y/(10^(1:(n))))  # split up into all possible integers

x[V1 == x[V1 %in% z, max(.SD),],, which = T]
```

This returns also multiple row id's in case there are duplicates. Instead of just returning row numbers, you could have a second column with IDs to be returned.

For a list of 20 million integers it takes much less than a second.

```
Unit: seconds
                                           expr        min          lq       mean      median         uq       max neval
 x[V1 == x[V1 %in% z, max(.SD), ], , which = T] 0.00076113 0.000871416 0.02571112 0.000945884 0.00109958 0.6195882    25
```